# Exporting a list to csv from a custom page

Tags: sharepoint-designer, 2016, filter, export, csv

I have a custom page created to allow users to be able to select their own parameters to filter items in a list using web-parts (with help from SharePoint designer 2013).

This filtered list needs to be exported with only the columns shown to CSV. There are no ribbons on the page to manipulate list or items. Therefore, i don't think i can trigger workflows either.

Google-ing only returns methods of exporting from lists or views.

Does anyone know how to do this?

The system does not have any sort of excel/office software

I forgot to mention that the export is triggered by users, so no power shell scripts, unless they can be triggered from the page.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is the problem? What works and what did not work?

Comment: i am not sure how to interact with the page to obtain the values that users will use to filter the data with, and apply that to the list to only export those items.
Thinking on another path, i am not sure how to directly access the resulting list and export those values

Comment: Can you be more specific? What WebParts have you on the page? How is the filtering done? What have you tried to do already?

Comment: sorry for the lack of information. i have a __choice__ filter web-part that filters the status of items, and 2 __date__ filter web-parts (__from date__ and __to date__)
so only items that fulfill both filters will be displayed on the page. right now, this is working and only items that fulfill the status condition in the time range will be displayed. **what i've tried**: put these web-parts on a list view instead, but the filters seem to be working differently there. i need to do an additional sort ascending/descending before the filters take effect

Comment: Which SharePoint version are you using? Would you be capable to write your own app?

Comment: SP2016. i could try, but i'm likely not familiar enough with sharepoint at this point.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a view to accomplish this, all the columns in the view will be exported to the CSV file.

Comment: but then i can't add web-parts to allow the user to filter the view as they desire

Comment: ok, nvm, i can, but they seem to be working differently as compared to on a custom page.setting a filter, i need to click and sort the list before the filter kicks in and hides the non-applicable items. my custom page applies the filter immediately upon selection

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard way to do this. Also, there is no easy way - using code - to do this. Sorry.